# C# Index and Range

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-8.0

In Preview 3 of .NET Core 3.0, [Microsoft explained in more detail](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-preview-3/) how **Index** and **Range** work.

```cs
int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
In this case we have array with 10 elements.
```

Using:

```cs
int[] subsetNums = nums[2..6];
```

This would take the elements: `{3,4,5,6}`. Starting with the element at index `2`—which makes perfect sense—but ending with element at index `5`. Why wouldn't it take the 6th element since you have put `6` in the brackets?

Comment: @DavidG The `to` index [is exclusive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges).

Comment: @GSerg Sounds like an answer to me... :)

Comment: @DavidG Did you read an article?

Comment: @DavidG I would prefer an answer from someone who is less confused about this than me.

Comment: @DavidG it wrote on microsoft com
// start with int[]
int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int lastNum = nums[^1]; // 10
int[] subsetNums = nums[2..6]; // {3, 4, 5, 6}

Comment: It is the universal way to handle ranges, across different languages.  You've always done it before, a new int[6] array doesn't make element 6 accessible either.

Comment: @HansPassant one can argue that the real universal way is the one [we all learned at high school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Including_or_excluding_endpoints): square brackets are inclusive, parentheses are exclusive. I suspect this confuses every programmer the first time :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The end index you specify is exclusive. One advantage of this approach is it makes it easier to reason about the number of elements you're extracting:

`2..6` extracts 4 elements, which is `6 - 2`.